# Что такое WinRT и с чем его едят?

Tags: c#, .net, winrt

Рихтер в своей книге целую главу посвятил данному механизму, но я так и не понял в каких сценариях его имеет смысл применять.

Это что-то типа убийцы COM, который нужно применять для межязыкового взаимодействия между управляемым модулем и неуправляемым? Или это вообще какая-то обертка над WinApi?

Comment: [_Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs. These APIs are for UWP app development on Windows 10._](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/)

Comment: @Grundy, ну если смотреть краем глаза, то там функциональность стандартного .NET. Всякие потоки я там увидел, например и тп вещи.

Comment: Это убийца WinAPI. Точнее, модернизированная замена WinAPI для store apps.

Comment: @VladD Т.е это кастрированный WinAPI или полноценная замена?

Comment: @iluxa1810 для полноценной замены он еще мало что умеет из возможностей WinAPI, но уже умеет то, чего в WinAPI никогда не было. Короче - игрушка на любителя. Меня пока не впечатлило, пощупайте, может понравится.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На самом деле, WinRT не является заменой или оберткой для какой либо из предыдущих технологий. **WinRT** - это принципиально новая технология, направленная на разработку приложений, которые имеют смысл на разных типах устройств. Приложение WinRT может использовать базовый API и работать на всех типах устройств, или использовать расширения API и работать под набором конкретных устройств (например, под ПК и смартфоном, ПК и Xbox и т.п.)

Первоначально эта технология возникла под Windows 8 и называлась WinRT. Позднее в Windows 10 она была заменена на аналогичную технологию **UWP**, которая охватывает больший набор устройств. Сейчас можно приближенно считать, что это одно и то же.

Приложения UWP/WinRT обладают следующими особенностями:

- Взаимодействие с ОС с помощью специального API Windows Runtime или ограниченного подмножества разрешенных API из Win32/COM и .NET
- Запуск в ограниченной среде, где приложения не имеют прямой доступ к оборудованию, реестру, всей файловой системе и т.п. WinRT приложения имеют доступ только к своей папке данных, а к другим папкам могут получать доступ с явного разрешения пользователя
- Распространение преимущественно через Магазин Windows, подобно распространению мобильных приложений, в противоположность обычному скачиванию инсталляторов с разных сайтов
- Разработка может осуществляться либо на С++ (с расширениями С++/CX для взаимодействия с компонентами WinRT), либо на .NET-языках
- Построение графического интерфейса с помощью XAML-фреймворка, похожего на WPF. В отличие от WPF, приложение строится не как набор окон, а как набор страниц, между которыми пользователь переходит внутри одного окна (как в веб-приложениях). Это позволяет создавать адаптивный интерфейс, имеющий смысл на разных типах устройств.

**WinRT не является "убийцей COM"**, что бы это не значило. COM жив и будет жить, более того, сами компоненты WinRT API внутри представляют из себя COM-объекты. WinRT-приложения, написанные на С++, могут взаимодействовать с ними либо традиционно, как с COM-объектами, либо с использованием специальных расширений языка C++/CX.

**WinRT не является "убийцей WinAPI"**, что бы это не значило. WinRT приложения, написанные на С++, могут как обычно взаимодействовать с подмножеством разрешенных Win32/COM API. Например, функция `CreateFile` будет доступна, а функции работы с реестром - нет. Конечно, это не позволяет обойти ограничения платформы, т.е. функция `CreateFile` также будет работать только с файлами в разрешенных папках. *Забавный факт: в WinRT нельзя этой функцией открыть устройство NUL, как следствие - [код, написанный из предположения, что оно всегда доступно, сломается при портировании под WinRT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/ru-RU/d66c545f-dc6d-406c-873f-ea9ee0c86239/uwp-nul-device?forum=desktopprogrammingru&forum=desktopprogrammingru)*.

**WinRT не является средством для организации взаимодействия между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом** (в  целом). Тем не менее, расширения языка C++/CX предоставляют возможность организовать взаимодействие между кодом на стандартном С++ и компонентами WinRT.

Подробнее: [Введение в работу с UWP приложениями](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)

Answer (score 0):

C++/WinRT — это полностью стандартная проекция языка C++17 для API среды выполнения Windows (WinRT), реализованная как библиотека на основе файлов заголовков и предназначенная для предоставления вам первоклассного доступа к современным интерфейсам API Windows.

См. [Введение в C++/WinRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt)